# How to restore part parameters of a LSTM model

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a LSTM model L1 for pre-training with the parameters: W-lstm, b-lstm, Wy, by and so on.

And I want to train a new LSTM model L2 with different Wy and by, supposing Wy2 and by2.

So, how to only restore the W-lstm and b-lstm from L1, and initiate Wy2 and by2? Then training.

saver.restore()?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get the best responses by posting a minimal version of your code, with clear examples of what you have tried. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

When you create the saver you can pass it a list of the variables to save.  Therefore you can create a saver just for the first LSTM.  Here is an example of what I mean.  (Note this is just code I typed into the browser so you may find a typo)  Just create the LSTM inside a variable scope and create a saver which only saves the variables in that scope.

```
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCel(1024)
with tf.variable_scope('L1') as scope:
    state = INITIAL_STATE
    for t in range(TIME_STEPS):
        output, state = lstm(input, state)
        scope.reuse_variables()

...

l1_saver = tf.train.Saver([v for v in tf.all_variables() if 'L1' in v.name])
```

Comment: well, when I train the L1 model, I have saved all the parameters. So under this situation, how to extract part of the parameters I need?

Comment: You could do a restore with the everything saver and then use the specific L1 saver to save just the part you need and then use the L1 saver in the future.

Comment: so you mean to train the model again? with two savers? a all saver and a specific L1 saver?

Comment: What if I have all ready trained the model and do not want to train again?

Comment: No just do the restore with the all saver then save right away with the L1 saver just to capture those parameters

Comment: could you give me an example? about how to restore? thanks!

Comment: Hi, so I use the l1_saver = tf.train.Saver(encode_img_W,....) and then restore. However, there is a problem with the lstm. The error is:
TypeError: Variable to save is not a Variable: Tensor("Const:0", shape=TensorShape([]), dtype=string)
So how to restore the lstm?

Comment: Can you give an example on restoring ? It is not clear how to use the second saver.